# Any real-time antivirus for Ubuntu?

Tags: security, antivirus

Is there any real-time anti virus for Ubuntu? Which antivirus is good and in real-time (I mean that, if I try to open an infected file or go to a bad website, it stops it). 
I read a post in [ubuntuguide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Precise_Network_Management#Security) and here is a part of it:
 Anti-virus

If you are running a file server, interface frequently with Windows drives or share files with Windows users, or use virtualization, you will want a virus checker for your Windows files.

Despite extensive misinformation, Linux is not immune from malware (witness the explosion of malware being created for the Linux-based Google Android systems). The malware is not usually spread within the OS itself (as long as the OS is a well-respected distribution obtained through official channels), but in trojan programs downloaded and installed by users outside of the normal software distribution channels (i.e. repositories) of the OS. There is always a danger to using programs downloaded from the Internet from sources other than respected repositories -- it is the primary reason that Debian and (K)Ubuntu retain tight control over their software repositories.

Any file can have malware embedded in it (which is trivial to achieve by concatenation, for example: `cat originalfile.avi malware.exe > originalfileplusmalware.avi`). The question is whether a user will try to open a file with a program (such as a media player) that has been compromised in a way that allows it to execute the code found in the infected media (e.g. .avi) file. This can occur not only for Windows users but for any OS (including Mac OSX and Linux) with a compromised program (e.g. media player). An example is the extensive problems the Mac OS community is currently having with the Flash player.

Routine scanning of any file downloaded from the Internet, any file imported from another user's computer (even a trusted source, since their attention to virus prevention may not be as compulsive as yours), or any attachment received in an email (even from a trusted sender) should be done with an anti-virus program. **So I think that there is a need for anti-virus in Ubuntu.**

Comment: Note that this question is about anti-virus which offers real-time protection.So don't flag it as duplicate.

Comment: antivirus against what? Windows platform or Ubuntu?

Comment: Anti-virus for Ubuntu

Comment: @Alvar My post is regarding a real-time 'antivirus'

Comment: A great many people claim there is no need for one, but is it really true? Well, IMHO it depends on your set up:
>Scenario 1

Comment: " or go to a bad website, it stops it)." is NOT the task for a virus scanner. You do that with a browser and an extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have noted, you probably do not need it. However, [comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php), [kaspersky](http://support.kaspersky.com/4317) and few others offer real-time antivirus protection

Comment: that is wrong, linux is not better than windows or mac in perspective of viruses. Were found a lot of issues with getting root permissions via vulnerabilities in the kernel, sudo, intel cpu and so on. Dont be the one from linux fanatics, who even dont know if he have a virus.   The basic is to enforce SeLinux + ClamAV. The next steps depends on a needs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there are any real-time [antivirus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus?action=show&redirect=AntiVirus) programs for Linux that scans websites etc. on the run.

Comment: why the linux community think that if they have linux, they r protected?! Linux have a lot of issues with security and obtaining root permissions from any user. Just read a specialized security topics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a one. If such a virus comes specifically for Linux, there will be always a way to remove it. Can you seriously find such virus for Linux??

Comment: There have been cases of linux malware.

Comment: Yes, but very rarely and most of them relied on the user to store, `chmod +x`, and execute a file from a suspicious source. Tough I disagree with Naveen: malware with root privileges can set up a hypervisor to mask its existence and prevent its removal from inside the system.

Answer (score 0):

How To Install Comodo Antivirus For Linux 1.1 X86-64 On Ubuntu 12.10 - Desktop X86-64:

http://postbin.djun.net/pages/article11.php

You should note that it only scans for WINDOWS viruses, as do most antiviral tools for linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried loading the Comodo one, the download link fails. I installed the [Sophos Antivirus for Linux](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx) It was pretty easy to get and install on my Debian install. I just do it for the same reason their site says "To prevent the Linux machine from becoming a distribution point,..." I would be remiss if I just stored inert viruses on my Computer for my Windows machines to pick up at some point. Sophos scans for all platform malware, not just linux "threats." If the link fails in the future, it's in their "Free Tools" section.

Also several tools work in Chromium as extensions for checking safety of domains. Avira has one that works across platforms in Chrome. Also, using a DNS that is filtered is really a great starting point! Like the ones available at [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/), which are free, and help filter out known malicious domains before you can proceed to them.

Answer (score 0):

There are antivirus software available for Ubuntu, but, you should use Intrusion Detection Prevention System and configure your Firewall very well. This would help to protect your system. Linux is no more immune to viruses, that is why I suggest you use IDPS and internal Firewall.

For IDS, Snort is available here: [Snort Page](https://www.snort.org)
and for Firewall in Ubuntu you have to type following command in Terminal:

1. `sudo ufw enable` - This will enable Firewall in your system.
2. `sudo ufw status` - This will show the status of your Firewall
   and also use iptables for defining rules.

To know currently configured rules in iptables type the following command:

3. `iptables -L`
   You may learn about iptables from this link: 
   [Iptables Page](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-contents.html)

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your advise.

Comment: Better, but you're still missing instructions about setting up IDS and some of your phrasing is unclear, like 'Linux is no more immune to anti-virus'.

Comment: okay will edit that too.

Comment: I forgot to say, welcome to AskUbuntu and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but Avast might (it does in Windows)
[How to Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-and-update-avast-antivirus-in-ubuntu)
Also you can use Firefox and install the extension 'WOT'.  It's not an anti-virus but it will warn you about potential attack sites you might click on.

Comment: AFAIK avast didn't

Comment: do **NOT install WOT**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html