# Antivirus for Ubuntu 18.04 with real-time protection

Tags: software-recommendation, antivirus

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, is there any antivirus that can protect me from virus when I'm installing packages from Ubuntu repository or install python packages with pip or conda? I know that there are third party tools for ClamAV, however I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any real-time antivirus for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352159/any-real-time-antivirus-for-ubuntu) and [Installing software with python pip](https://askubuntu.com/q/557280/)

Comment: Thank you @karel, however the suggested Comodo only support up to Ubuntu 12, and Ubuntu 18.04 is not supported, am I wrong?

Comment: LOL. From the repos? Really? If there would be a virus in the ubuntu repositories it would be the -death- of Ubuntu. Users would end it and switch to another OS. "am I wrong?" yes. it is available for all releases. Mind that virusscanners work for scanning WINDOWS files. For Ubuntu it is a waste of time and resources. All you need to do is stick to official resources.

Comment: @Rinzwind recently, malware has been found that effects all Linux's.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no currently supported real-time AV's that work with 18.04. Install clamav, and scan your downloaded files as required.

Comment: Malware is more than just virus. There is no active virus (you know one that installs itself and propegates to other machines without interference) that infects Linux machines.  There is a lot of crap out there sure. But again: tell me how you get this from official repositories? Not going to happen. It would be the death of a discribution.

Comment: If you install with pip in a Python virtual environment you install Python packages as a normal user, not root and that is your first line of defense against malware carried by untrusted Python packages that are installed via pip.

Comment: I don't know I'm too cautious or not but recently zero-day attack and supply chain attack for linux system has been more and more frequent, that's why I consider installing an antivirus or anti-malware software for my ubuntu machine. However there seems few free solutions available, so I will try clamav and scan the filesystem each time I receive files or installe packages. Thank you every one.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I'm not good at OS security, so maybe I'm too cautious. Due to the network speed, I need to switch to third party repository mirrors sometimes, I dont't know that's dangerous or not.

Comment: @karel, thank you. for the reason that I need all the users can access the python environment, and nobody can delete or modify the python packages, I installed python environment in `/opt/` directory, so I need to use root user each time I install python packages, , is this dangerous?

Comment: Anyone can upload a Python package to the Python Package Index (PyPI) and then it's immediately installable by pip with minimal oversight by the maintainers of PyPI. Rational control of root permissions is one the fundamental concepts of Linux security.

Comment: There's a whole thread discussing this with overall good advice here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140679/antivirus-for-ubuntu-18-04/1140685#1140685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few antivirus software for Ubuntu but they are old such as clamav and comodo but you can check out Sophos.

Comment: why do say it's old? Clamav last updated last week. The database is constantly updated.